# Mouse cursor not changing on hover in Qt Apps (22.04)

Tags: 22.04, qt, cursor

Usually, the mouse cursor adapts to whatever it's hovering over. However, for maybe one or two weeks now (probably since some update), this will sometimes spontaneously stop working in Qt apps until I hover over some non-Qt app. This might sound like a minor inconvenience, but is actually incredibly annoying and impractical. Does anyone have any idea what I could look into to solve this?

Edit: I'm on a completely generic installation of Ubuntu (GNOME desktop)

Comment: You've not specified what desktop you're using, only highlighting Qt; so is it Kubuntu/KDE? or Lubuntu/LXQt?   From your description, I'd check your suggested Qt5 themes (*ensuring they match your GTK themes if using a GTK desktop*).  If it's from an update as you suggest, did you explore your update logs to see what changed around the time it started to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a screen overlay that I used to reduce my screen brightness below the minimum. This seems to happen with any kind of screen overlay, so the only working solution is to avoid overlays or Qt apps.